# Are there taxi stands at Tbilisi's Navtlugi train station?

Tags: taxis, georgia-country, train-stations, tbilisi

I'll be arriving by Train to the Navtlugi Train Station in southeastern Tbilisi, and Need to catch a cab to the Ortachala bus Station from there. What are the possibilities of finding a cab at Navtlugi Station?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any problem at all at finding a cab at Navtlugi or wherever you want in Tbilisi. Just rise you hand on the road and any free car will stop near you.
 And also **I am sure** that plenty of cabs reside on the Navtlugi station.
However, if you want to be super safe, you can call taxi by phone with following numbers:

> 2 717 717
>   291 14 14
>   2939 100
>   2535 535
>   2200 200
>   0322 10 50 50
>   2 201 201
>   2 30 88 88
>   2 377 877
>   2 939 939
>   247 77 44
>   293 91 00
>   291 14 14
>   274 74 74
>   2 27 26 26
>   551 999 244
>   571 999 244
>   230 03 01